# Issues subclassing UIVisualEffect

Tags: ios, swift, uivisualeffectview

I am trying to subclass UIVisualEffect but I am having issues implementing the correct init methods. So far I have this:

```
import UIKit

class BlurView: UIVisualEffect {



    init(effect: UIVisualEffect?) {
        super.init(effect)
        print("Init 1 called")

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        print("Init 2 called")
    }



}
```

I am getting the error: "Missing the argument coder in the call". I have also tried:

```
import UIKit

class BlurView: UIVisualEffect {



    init(effect: UIVisualEffect?) {
        super.init()
        print("Init 1 called")

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        print("Init 2 called")
    }



}
```

This complains that I haven't implemented the init method. I tried doing this but still couldn't get it working. Any ideas how to go about implementing these methods? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo, you want to subclass `UIVisualEffectView`, not `UIVisualEffect`.

They are different `UIVisualEffectView` inherits from `UIView` and apply the `UIVisualEffect` that you pass in. `UIVisualEffect` is just the effect.

```
class BlurView: UIVisualEffectView {
    override init(effect: UIVisualEffect?) {
        super.init(effect: effect)
    }


    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
}
```